# Facebook Login using PHP SDK not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

```
<?php
  require_once('facebook.php');
  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxx',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        echo "1";
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
     echo "2";
    }
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I go to the mysite.com/fbconect.php, it is a white page with a link LOGIN. When i click login, it is going to the facebook page login.  After I Logged In, i go back to mysite.com/fbconect.php then It displays, Login link again with Echoed "1". The URL of mysite.com became mysite.com/fbconect.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: When your code reaches the `echo "1"` bit, that means you’re getting an exception … so have a look at what message the exception has!

Comment: where can i see the message? IT is showing only a white page.

Comment: echo $e->getMessage(); after echo "1";

Comment: oh, it changes now. It Echoed "2".

Comment: Again, echoed "1" .. with message, couldn't connect to host.

Comment: You authentication flow should redirect you back to your page. Does this happen? Or do you log in to Facebook and then open your page in another browser window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code.

Be sure:

1. The facebook user used for the test has authorized the app
2. This code just run into a PHP page deployed on the website specified in both:

   - `Facebook Developers` site -> `App > YourApp > Basic` ->  `App Domains`
   - `Facebook Developers` site -> `App > YourApp > Basic` ->  `Website with Facebook Login`

[image]

Maybe you are logged in with a user that has not already accepted your fb app. 
In this case you will see "*Please login.1*"

If you'll see "*Please login.2*", sure you're code have caught and exception.
For example if your read this:

```
OAuthException
Error validating access token: User YYYYYYYY has not authorized application XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
```

very likely your fb user have removed your app from his/her list.
Or if you see

```
Couldn't connect to host
```

This means the system you're working on most likely blocks outgoing connections.

If you want a test user that has already accepted your fb app, you can create one from `Facebook Developers` site go into  "`Apps > YourApp > Developer Roles`"

In case you want get authorization from the user you can change your code:

```
<?php
  require_once('facebook.php');
  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'yyyyyy',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
      function render_login($facebook) {
          $canvas_page = 'http://www.yoursite.com/';
          // HERE YOU ASK THE USER TO ACCEPT YOUR APP AND SPECIFY THE PERMISSIONS NEEDED BY
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_photos,friends_photos', 'redirect_uri'=>$canvas_page));
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
      }

    if($user_id) {
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        render_login($facebook);
        echo "1";
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }
    } else {
       render_login($facebook);
       echo "2";
    }
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do i need to put in App domain? Site URL? and Unity binary URL?

Comment: Just updated the answer to explain how specify your website domain.

Comment: Maybe also better create a function render_login in order to render the correct login url in any case.

Comment: still echoed "Please Login. 1 Couldn't connect to host"

Comment: Here is my Site.. http://musichat.zz.mu .. Can you visit it and tell me whats wrong?

Comment: @JohnBobs I have tried your site and even if the authentication process was completed successfully (I see your app within my FB Apps Settings) your page still returns me `Please login.2`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40867/discussion-between-freedev-and-john-bobs)

Comment: I've tried this and I do not seem to be getting through with it... I have the redirect_uri set as required( with trailing slash) I have authorized the app but I keep getting echo 2 instead of 1...my url is http://triniscene.com/tsv7/stream/